# Why can't I install cPickle | Pip needs upgrading?

Tags: python, pycharm, pickle

When trying to install cPickle using pycharm I get this:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Edwin\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\cpickle 
>   You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.1.2 is available.
>   You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

So then when I go command prompt to type in:

> python -m pip install --upgrade pip

I get this:

> 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

So how do I install cPickle?

BTW: I am using windows & python 3.5.1

Comment: If you open a command prompt and type `python` in, do you get the same thing?

Comment: use full path to `python`.

Comment: Python probably needs to be added to your environment variables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7

Comment: try just: pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: I thought `cPickle` was part of the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/) in 2.7 anyway?

Comment: `pip` is python module like `cPickle` - if you know where/how to install `cPickle` with `PyCharm` then try the same way upgrade `pip` with `PyCharm`.

Comment: @code11 yes, I am using python 3.5.1

Comment: If you're in python 3 then I'm reasonably sure that `pickle` is the same as the `cPickle` from Python 2, and the Python 2 `pickle` was removed.

Comment: @roganjosh yes you are right. It is just pickle :D: EDIT: Though does anyone know how to upgrade pip

Comment: For reference if anyone lands on this question somehow: https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#library-changes Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to solve the issue with upgrading pip.

Comment: @Whud same issue but with pip instead of python

Comment: What about the suggestion by @code11 ?

Comment: @Edwinthebreadwin are you running cmd as administrator ?

Comment: @roganjosh and I have tried just typing in python and get the same thing.

Comment: Then at a complete guess, you're pointing `pycharm` to some python installation file that hasn't actually been installed on Windows itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, this is most likely because Python is not added to your environment variables. If you do not want to touch your environment variables, and assuming your Python is installed in `C:\Python35\`,

1. Navigate tp `C:\Python35\` in Windows Explorer
2. Go to the address bar and type `cmd` to shoot up a command prompt in that directory

Alternatively to steps 1 and 2, directly shoot up a command prompt, and `cd` to your Python installation Directory (default: `C:\Python35`)

3. Type `python -m pip install pip --upgrade` there

Comment: Thanks this also allowed me to install a bunch of other libraries :D